# Making Navigation bar in bootstrap still responsive

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, uinavigationbar

Im using bootstrap framework for my UI. I had made a navigation bar using the same framework. When I reduce the screen size I'm getting this output

[image]

Still, if I reduce the window size I could see collapse button like this

[image]

.If I reduce the window, I don't want to see like the one which is in the image reduced window. Instead, if I had reduced the window size, is it possible to see the collapse button without the reduced window stage?

Comment: do you saw example https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ ?

Comment: Well yeah. I did. But didn't.t know which CSS property to change. Should i wanna change the overflow property of .navbar?

Answer (score 1):

One option is you might want to try and mesure the width of the window and record the pixel width when it transitions from the main nav into the collapsed nav.

You can do this via the console in Google Chrome:

[image]

Once you have the correct width write a media query in your CSS like so:

```
 @media (max-width: WIDTH) {
   .main-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .small-nav {
  display: visible
 }
}
```

WIDTH in this case would be the pixel width that Google Chrome provides (ie '600px' or whatever). Make sure 'main-nav' and 'small-nav' are renamed to reflect the class names of both your navigations.

Comment: Will it works for mobile and tablet too? And also should i want to include the above in my css as it is or WIDTH should be replaced by any? Am new to Bootstrap.

Comment: Good questions! I've included a diagram and further explained it. Let me know if you still don't understand

Answer (score 0):

You have to add media css resize width like below and just decrease padding     of element .

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .nav > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 7px;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Toggle menu comeup while your window resize width 768px.